# Why there is a payload length field in the IP header?

Tags: header, ip, network-protocols

16 bits are used for "Total length" in IPv4 and "Payload length" in IPv6. Ethernet frame header already contains a 16-bit length field. Even though only some of its possible values are used to indicate length, it should by itself unambiguously specify the total length of the payload and thus the total length of the IP datagram. Why specify it again in the IP header? (and again in UDP?)

Answer (score 1):

IP and ethernet are on different layers in the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). A service that is on layer n doesn't know anything that happens on layer n+1, the data is completely opaque to it. As such, certain things like length have to be repeated.

Comment: But the length is not repeated on higher layers of the OSI model, is it? And IP addresses from the IP header are available on higher layers too, why not the length?

Comment: No it isn't, as it is not needed, if needed, they are able to access the lower layers' information. Data length is only important on the 3 lower layers, as they actually deal with splitting up data to transmit it. As the lower layer doesn't care what is being encapsulated in a data packet and can't access it, the length has to be repeated.

Comment: But why cannot IP get the length from a lower layer, just as the IP source address is gotten from IP by higher layers? Is it for interoperability with lower layers that do not provide length information?

Comment: The OSI model is designed as much for logic as it is for practicality. You're right that higher layers can, as needed, access contents from lower layers, but they are usually kept separated for clarity and flexibility. This way, higher levels can choose to treat lower level data as atomic, and pass it around without bothering to read into it.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that Layer2 not necessarily is Ethernet.

IP is providing logical layering and addressing over different lower layer networks.
So Layer3 has its own length and doesn't worry about layer2.
And let layer2 takes care of its own length.